# Font size button using JavaScript, HTML and PHP

Tags: javascript, button

I want to create three buttons on my PHP/HTML page using JavaScript/JQuery by which on pressing respective button I can manage to increase size of text in my button. 
Also, I want to keep this selection for other content of my website. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the font size value in [`SESSION`](http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php) or [`COOKIES`](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html).

When you move to another page, then get the value and set the font size again.

Answer (score 0):

See this example, using jquery [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/26byY/2/) .